# Does anyone recognize this art, it seems familiar.. 1980's maybe?

Tags: story-identification, cover-art

> [image: Signature and text at the bottom of the image with a signature from the author][Click to preview in new tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTkwR.jpg)

> [image: Naked lady posing with a planet-like object in the background][Click to preview in new tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gveEd.jpg)

I have this original art and am trying to find who the creator is.. It seems familiar.. Has a 1980's feel.

Comment: Are you sure this is science fiction or fantasy? It’s got a planet in the background, sure, but those exist in real life. And unrealistic portrayals of women may be fantasy of a certain sort, but not the type in the site name. To be honest, I’m not totally sure that even *obviously* fantastical drawings would be on-topic (if there’s no story associated with them).

Comment: That is to say, do you have some reason to think that this is cover art, or was made by someone of interest to science fiction and fantasy fandom?

Comment: I've hidden the images under spoiler tags because of nudity, I dunno. seemed appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

The same painting, *down to the numbering (3/12)*, and one other from same artist, was found on a [Goodwill auction site](https://www.shopgoodwill.com/Item/45902954), but they don't give the artist name.  I would think that given the materials of the framing these are both from before the 1980's (the yellowing of tape on the back of the frame makes me think they glue is quite old, probably from before the 80's).

[image: Goodwill images]

From here, it would probably be best to try to find a signature match somewhere else, but I have not idea what it says:

[image: Artists sig]

Comment: The signature's handwriting is a little difficult for me to read, but the first name could be "Arteto", "Artets", or maybe "Artato" (though I doubt that last one). Last name looks to be either "Proal" or "Prool", but that last letter could easily be a stylized cursive 'f' as well, so if might be "Proaf" or "Proof". Not sure how much this helps.

Comment: @Pleiades That says "Artists proof.". The signature is the scribble farther to the right.

Comment: @Buzz Ohhhhh... (/_-) Well, obviously, I'm smart. Not real sure what the scribble says either, but I wanna say the first name is "Jon", although I don't think that's super helpful to this search.

Comment: @Pleiades "Jon" was my initial guess at the first name, based just on the writing.  However, as I note in my answer, it's also consistent with "Jim."

Answer (score -1):

The title is given in image:  "pictorial ode to a torn woman."

I recognized the style (with the peculiar musculature), and I was pretty sure it was somebody who had done some early illustrations for Dungeons & Dragons.  However, I couldn't quite figure the artists's name, so I had to go through lots of Googling to figure it out.

It appears to be [Jim Roslof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Roslof).  I suspect this may be very early work, since it is fairly crude and does not have one of the later standard signatures that Roslof used.  Note, however, that the handwritten name is clearly consistent with "Jim Roslof," although it's not possible to be sure that's what it says.  Searching over images shows that Roslof used many different signatures styles over his career.  Here is a clearly legible version of his name.

[image: Written name]

Obviously, this name bears scarce resemblance to the signature in the above artwork.  Note, however, the last letters of the words "Jim" and "Roslof."  The terminal "m" trails off just like the written "n" at the end of "woman" in the picture title.  Even more clearly, the quite distinctive "f" at the end of "Roslof" (apart from the underline that crosses it) is practically identical to the letter at the end of "Artists proof."

The most objectively similar picture by Roslof that I could find with a bit of Googling is this image of the goddess Hecate from the *Deities & Demigods Cyclopedia*.

[image: Hecate]

Note the similar angularity in the figure.  The women's feet and bellies are especially similar.  The same style of hatched shading is visible in the moon behind Hecate and on some of the flames at the unknown figure's feet.  There is also the similarity imagery of the (occluded?) moon.

Comment: I don’t know enough to say whether the art styles are similar, but given that the picture isn’t *obviously* cover art, and your identification is based mainly on similar artistic styles (and thus it’s not certain that the previous image is associated with fantasy even in the fandom sense), I don’t know that this is on-topic. As for the signature, it indeed doesn’t look much like the one in the figure picture you found - all the letters are well-formed and barely connected in the signature your image, and they’re fairly indecipherable and connected in the OP’s image. It’s a big difference.

Comment: Roslof's signature and the signature in the charcoal work are _nothing_ alike.

Comment: https://www.shopgoodwill.com/Item/45902954. They didn't know either.

Comment: And I’d expect someone selling a Roslof piece from before he was semi-famous to sell it for a little more than $27, too.

Comment: @Adamant Given that the seller clearly doesn't know the artist's identity, that seems irrelevant.

Comment: Good point. In any case, I happen to think that this would be perfectly on-topic on some general art site, if they accept ID questions. But without being able to firmly say that this is an illustration for a speculative fiction work, or even whether it’s necessarily by someone associated with SF....